# display links according to whether or not user is logged in

Tags: php, session, authentication

I'm working on PHP authentication; I want to make sure that the user is connected or not. If the user is not connected, a "login | sign up" link appears; otherwise the name will be shown on the top page next to a Logout link. Here is my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
    if(!empty($_SESSION['niv'])){?>
    <ul class="acc_nav">
        <li><span class="user">Welcome <strong>Saad Berrada</strong></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|</li>
        <li id="un-login"><a href="#"><span>Logout</span></a>
    </ul>
<?php }  else {
    ?>
    <ul class="acc_nav">
        <li><a href="#"><span>Login</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a></li>
        <li><a href="" data-reveal-id="myModal_197"><span>Sign up</span></a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php }?>
```

even if I go through authentication, the Login/Sign up links that appears !

here is authentication scipt

```
    require_once 'Connexion.php';
    $c = new Connexion();
    $e = $_POST['email_ca'];
    $p = md5($_POST['pass_ca']);
    $c->query("select id_candidat from candidat where email='" .$e. "' and pass='" .$p. "'");
    $rs = $c->single();

  if($u = $rs){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['niv'] = $u['niveau'];
    header("location:home.php?$e");
} else {
    ob_start();
    echo 'Email or password is inccorect';
    header("refresh: 2;location:login-signup.php");
    ob_flush();
}
```

and this is Connexion class

```
<?php
Class Connexion {

private $host = "localhost";
private $user = "root";
private $pass = "";
private $dbname = "cvtheque";
private $dbh;
private $stmt;

public function __construct() {
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . $this->host . ';dbname=' . $this->dbname;
    // Set options
    $options = array(
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    );
    // Create a new PDO instanace
    try {
        $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $this->user, $this->pass, $options);
    }
    // Catch any errors
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connexion Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function query($query) {
    $this->stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($query);
}

public function bind($param, $value, $type = null) {
    if (is_null($type)) {
        switch (true) {
            case is_int($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_INT;
                break;
            case is_bool($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                break;
            case is_null($value):
                $type = PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                break;
            default:
                $type = PDO::PARAM_STR;
        }
    }
    $this->stmt->bindValue($param, $value, $type);
}

public function execute() {
    return $this->stmt->execute();
}

public function resultset() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function single() {
    $this->execute();
    return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

public function rowCount() {
    return $this->stmt->rowCount();
}

public function lastInsertId() {
    return $this->dbh->lastInsertId();
}

public function beginTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
}

public function endTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->commit();
}

public function cancelTransaction() {
    return $this->dbh->rollBack();
}

public function debugDumpParams() {
    return $this->stmt->debugDumpParams();
 }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [function.session-start is displaying on sign-in-action page with other correct links why so and how to check session for sign-in-action-form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138325/function-session-start-is-displaying-on-sign-in-action-page-with-other-correct-l)

Comment: ...does `niv` have a value? Where is your session set?

Comment: i used var_dump($_SESSION); it gives array (size=1)
'niv' => null. it means that the variable is null

Comment: `if($u = $rs){` -- what is this line supposed to do? `$u` doesn't appear to be defined and this line assigns `$rs` to `$u`, when I would guess you want to check for equality/truth. Also -- is the html/php code you've posted from `home.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember - you need to call session_start() on your sign in processing page otherwise session variables won't actually be created. Also try var_dump($_SESSION) and let us know what output you get.

Comment: i used var_dump($_SESSION); it gives array (size=1) 'niv' => null. it means that the variable is null

Comment: `if($u = $rs)` is wrong - this assigns the value of $rs to $u. It should presumably be `$u == $rs`. Further, you haven't declared `session_start()` in your authentication script. This should likely clear the issue.

Comment: I have found the solution
$rs = $c->single();
while($rs){
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['niv'] = TRUE;
    header("location:home.php?$e");
}

Comment: `session_start()` should *nearly* **always** be [declared at the start of your PHP file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php). It also helps us debug ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['niv'])){?>
    <ul class="acc_nav">
        <li><span class="user">Welcome <strong>Saad Berrada</strong></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|</li>
        <li id="un-login"><a href="#"><span>Logout</span></a>
    </ul>
<?php }  else {
    ?>
    <ul class="acc_nav">
        <li><a href="#"><span>Login</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a></li>
        <li><a href="" data-reveal-id="myModal_197"><span>Sign up</span></a></li>
        </li>
    </ul>
<?php }?>
```

Using Isset of Session , will solve your problem.

I hope this will helpful for you.

Comment: That means your session is not started from the server. Please check that you getting any vales. Just check 

echo "<pre>";print_r($_SESSION); echo "</pre>";

Comment: i dont knwo why session is null

Answer (score 0):

Most Guaranteed way

```
      <?php
       @session_start();
       if(isset($_SESSION['niv']) && $_SESSION['niv'] != ""){?>
          <ul class="acc_nav">
            <li><span class="user">Welcome <strong>Saad Berrada</strong>  
            </span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|</li>
            <li id="un-login"><a href="#"><span>Logout</span></a>
         </ul>
      <?php }  
      else {
      ?>
        <ul class="acc_nav">
           <li><a href="#"><span>Login</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;|</a></li>
           <li><a href="" data-reveal-id="myModal_197"><span>Sign up</span></a></li>
        </ul>
     <?php }?>
```